# Is there a way to know the portion of a row in group in groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am working on this table:

| plaza | station | name | ID | g1 | g2 | g3 | location | g_avg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 45 | 1 | aaa | 45_1_aaa | 4 | 5 | 6 | sun | 5.00 |
| 45 | 2 | aaa | 45_2_aaa | 1 | 5 | 2 | sun | 2.67 |
| 46 | 1 | bbb | 46_1_bbb | 8 | 9 | 3 | sun | 6.67 |
| 47 | 1 | ccc | 47_1_ccc | 4 | 5 | 0 | sun | 3.00 |
| 47 | 2 | ccc | 47_2_ccc | 3 | 4 | 7 | sun | 4.67 |
| 45 | 3 | aaa | 45_3_aaa | 3 | 4 | 0 | sun | 2.33 |
| 34 | 1 | ddd | 34_1_ddd | 19 | 29 | 28 | moon | 25.33 |
| 47 | 3 | eee | 47_3_eee | 1 | 2 | 2 | moon | 1.67 |
| 48 | 1 | fff | 48_1_fff | 1 | 2 | 1 | moon | 1.33 |
| 49 | 1 | ggg | 49_1_ggg | 2 | 1 | 1 | moon | 1.33 |
| 49 | 2 | ggg | 49_2_ggg | 1 | 1 | 1 | moon | 1.00 |

I am running a groupby on the location and ID columns and I want to get, for each row, the g_avg divided by the sum of g_average for rows in that location.

The code im using is this

```
data.groupby(['location', 'ID']).apply(lambda x: len(x['g_avg']) /x['g_avg'].sum() * 100)
```

and this is the result I get:

[image]

What I was hoping to achieve is this:

[image]

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `groupby.transform` to find the total `g_avg` for each location; then divide `g_avg` values by these sums:

```py
df['ratio'] = df['g_avg'] / df.groupby('location')['g_avg'].transform('sum') * 100
out = df[['location','ID','ratio']]
```

Output:

```py
   location        ID      ratio
0       sun  45_1_aaa  20.542317
1       sun  45_2_aaa  10.969597
2       sun  46_1_bbb  27.403451
3       sun  47_1_ccc  12.325390
4       sun  47_2_ccc  19.186524
5       sun  45_3_aaa   9.572720
6      moon  34_1_ddd  82.615786
7      moon  47_3_eee   5.446836
8      moon  48_1_fff   4.337900
9      moon  49_1_ggg   4.337900
10     moon  49_2_ggg   3.261579
```